# Kendo html bounded form reset

Tags: javascript, forms, mvvm, kendo-ui, observable

I am trying to reset an html bounded form viewModel on button click that uses a observable object but after the reset(html reset), it doesn't allow input to form to pull new data on click.

Workflow: I have a form where user inputs an id and clicks a button where the remote datasource pulls the data into the form. After the data is loaded, the user would click the Clear(reset) button to load a blank form to search another id to load new data but after the Clear(reset), it is not allowing the form to retrieve the new data.

**Model**

```
 var formModel = kendo.data.Model.define({                            
                            id: "investigation_id",
                            ...
  });
```

**Datasource**

```
var formSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
                     ... });
```

**Observable**

```
 var form = kendo.observable({
                            dataSource: formSource,                                                         
                            forms: new formModel(),
                            standard_ind: 0, change_type: 0, 
                            resolution_type: 0,resolution_sub_type: 0,                                                      
                            getstd: function(){ return this.get("standard_ind"); }, 
                            getchg: function(){ return this.get("change_type"); },                                                        
                            getrestype: function(){ return this.get("resolution_type"); },
                            getresstype: function(){ return this.get("resolution_sub_type"); },
                            ...
                            goReset: function(){                                    
                                    invReset();
                            }

kendo.bind($("#triage_form"), form); 

function invReset(){
                            $('#sr_error_message').text('').fadeOut();  
                                $('#subform').hide();$('#upd').hide();$('#save').show();                                 
                                newModel = new formModel();
                                form.dataSource.data(newModel);
                                console.log("reset form",form.forms);
                                $('#sr_number').focus();
                        };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the JS .reset() with loading data again to load blank observable again and form is resetting correctly now.

```
...
document.getElementById("triage_form").reset();
getdata();    ;initiates blank model
...
```